# Is it necessary to override == and != operators when overriding the Equals method? (.NET)

Tags: .net, operators, overriding, equals-operator

Or it's advisable to do that?
Why?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

See the [guidelines for overriding Equals() and operator==](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx).

Quote:

> By default, the operator == tests for reference equality by determining whether two references indicate the same object. Therefore, reference types do not have to implement operator == in order to gain this functionality. When a type is immutable, that is, the data that is contained in the instance cannot be changed, overloading operator == to compare value equality instead of reference equality can be useful because, as immutable objects, they can be considered the same as long as they have the same value. It is not a good idea to override operator == in non-immutable types.

Basically:

If you want == and != to behave like `Equals(..)` and `!Equals(..)` you need to implement the operators. You typically do this only with immutable types.

Answer (score 5):

See [Guidelines for Implementing Equals and the Equality Operator (==)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h9bszxx(VS.71).aspx)

For Value Types (structs) "Implement == any time you override the Equals method"

For Reference Types (classes), "Most reference types, even those that implement the Equals method, should not override ==." The exception is for immutable classes and those with value-like semantics.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all the answers already here, don't forget to ensure `GetHashCode()` is consistent as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are overriding the equals method and still want to be able to check for equality (or inequality) then you should probably override the == and != methods as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary, but a smart thing to do.

If you are creating a framework and another developer other than you are going to use the object you should override the == and !=.  That way when a developer may use it they at least have the right logic to compare the 2 objects rather than just are the same in memory.

I would ensure that your == & != do call your equals method.

Answer (score 1):

It would be advisable, as it would be unexpected if:

```
if (foo == bar)
```

...behaved differently to:

```
if (foo.Equals(bar))
```

Comment: There are many cases where `foo==bar` will behave differently from `foo.Equals(bar)`.  A mistaken belief in their equivalence is apt to cause far trouble than a recognition that they cannot always behave the same and should not be expected to [indeed, the Framework has some inconsistencies in what `Equals` means which stem from an IMHO misplaced desire to make it match `==`].

Comment: @supercat a good example is when comparing nullable types, Equals is smart and checks HasValue for each side.

Comment: @Gary: I was thinking more of things like `Decimal`.  It's useful to have a means of comparison which regards ranked objects as equal if neither ranks above the other, but it's also useful to have a means of equality testing which can recognize equally-ranked objects (e.g. 1.0d and 1.00d) as distinct.  IMHO, such objects should yield opposite comparison results with `==` and `.Equals`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary, nobody will kill you if you do not do that.

However, do notice that it is often more natural to write (A == B) than A.Equals(B). If you provide both methods, it will be easier for consumers of your code.

Answer (score 1):

in A.Equals(B)  A cannot be null
in A == B either can be null

Answer (score 1):

Overriding == to make it call Equals strikes me as a generally bad idea for reference types.  If you override == to make it call Equals, then I don't think there's a way for a user of your code to test whether two object references refer to the exact same object (versus an object with equal properties).

If people want to test instances of your classes for value equality then surely they should just call Equals, saving == for testing reference equality specifically.

Comment: You can use `Object.ReferenceEquals` to specifically check reference equality.

Comment: Although it's possible to use `Object.ReferenceEquals`, it's pretty clunky.  I regard the C# use of the `==` token for both the overloadable-equality-test and reference-equality-test operators as one of the biggest design mistakes in the language.