# Why overriding == must override equals?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it necessary to override == and != operators when overriding the Equals method? (.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222035/is-it-necessary-to-override-and-operators-when-overriding-the-equals-metho)

C# compiler prompts me that I should override equals if overriding ==, I just want to know why?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1222035/238902

Comment: @Default actually, I don't think it is a duplicate - but they are linked. This one is "when providing ==, should I override Equals?" (to which the answer is generally: yes), where-as the other is "when overriding Equals, do I have to provide == ?" (to which the answer is generally: no, not really)

Answer (score 12):

If you are re-defining equality via `==`, it gets **really** confusing if `==` does something very different to `.Equals`, and `.Equals` has to be the fallback because when the type is not known at compile time, only `.Equals` is available. As a consequence, defining `==` really means: defining `==`, `!=`, `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, and possibly implementing `IEquatable<T>` for some `T`.

Comment: +1 Yeah, `double.NaN` stings when you get that wrong :-)

Comment: It's not possible for `==` and `Equals` to behave identically in all situations, and I don't think they should be expected to.  What would be more helpful would be for `==` to be consistent in the places where it is usable, and `Equals` to be consistent everywhere (since it's usable everywhere).  A rule that numeric types representing the same number should compare `==`, even if they differ in other regards, while only things which are 100% equivalent should compare as `Equals`, would IMHO be more helpful than the mishmosh that exists now.

Comment: As it is, there's no nice way to define e.g. a dictionary that would map `Decimal` values to their string representations, because a dictionary cannot distinguish the numbers `1.0m` and `1.00m` [whose string representations should differ].  The `==` operator should regard those values as equal, but that doesn't mean `Equals` should.  Further, the way `==` overloads are defined, it often fails to implement an equivalence relation and doesn't really test for numerical equality, since e.g. `16777217==16777216.0f`.

Answer (score 4):

Because otherwise you'll have two semantically similar operations potentially yielding different results, meaning a lot of confusion.

I'm not sure if the compiler stops you or if it is just a warning, but in either case it's usually good to make sure they behave the same.

There is something like this with `double.NaN == double.NaN` versus `double.NaN.Equals(double.NaN)`.

Comment: +1: interesting, I wasn't aware of `double.NaN.Equals( double.NaN) == true`.

Answer (score 1):

Because otherwise you will get different results depending on how you do the comparison.

Doing `x == y` could give a different result from doing `y == x` (if `x` and `y` are different types). Other comparisons, like looking for the value in a list or using it as a key in a dictionary doesn't use the `==` operator, so that wouldn't work at all.

Comment: Why could be different? What has order to do?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Because `x == y` would use the `==` operator on the `x` value, but `y == x` would use the `==` operator on the `y` value. If they are implemented differently (e.g. `y` uses the default object comparison) they give different results.

Comment: Ah, I see. But that would happen if `x` and `y` have different types. If both have same type, `x == y` or `y == x` should behave the same way. Maybe you should point out this in our answer.

Comment: Nice!! Because otherwise I had doubts about the content of the answer. Thank you for accepting my suggestion